# Assign different text name in an array button using different function

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a 2x2 button array and I want to give it a different text name.

```
Button[,] btnSeat = new Button[2, 2];
        private void initializeBoard()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                        btnSeat[i, j] = new Button();
                        btnSeat[i, j].Width = 90;
                        btnSeat[i, j].Height = 90;
                        pnlSeat.Controls.Add(btnSeat[i, j]);


                }
         }
```

IT will have an output like this

[image]

How can I assign a text using different function

```
public void assignName()
{
  //assign button names
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you from passing the button as a parameter?

```
public void assignName(Button  button)
{ 
   button.Text = "ex";
}
```

**Edit**

Since your naming convention is known ahead of time, you can just use a map.

```
string[,] buttonNames = new string[2,2];
buttonNames[0,0] = "dog";
// continue
```

Then if you want to use the separate function, you would need to pass in 3 parameters.

```
public void assignName(Button button, int row, int column)
{
    string[,] buttonNames = new string[2,2];
    buttonNames[0,0] = "dog";
    // continue

   buttonText.Text = buttonNames[row][column];
}
```

*Notes*

I would either make the name map static at the class level and assigned in a static constructor or dispense with the function, declare the name map in the initializeBoard method and just use it in there.

For example

```
private void initializeBoard()
{
   string[,] buttonNames = new string[2,2];
   buttonNames[0,0] = "dog";
   // continue

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      {
         btnSeat[i, j] = new Button();
         btnSeat[i, j].Width = 90;
         btnSeat[i, j].Height = 90;
         btnSeat[i, j].Text = buttonNames[row][column];
         pnlSeat.Controls.Add(btnSeat[i, j]);
      }
   }
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: how can i make them have different names?

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. How do you want them named? Is there some algorithm that you want to follow?

Comment: just manually, for example btnSeat[0,0].Text = "dog";  btnSeat[1,0].Text = "chair";

Comment: @charlie9495 Just put that after your loop, then?

Comment: Just add a string parameter to this for a custom text

Comment: Can't. The second text gives a NullReferenceException

Comment: @ReedCopsey Ah yes sorry I didn't see the word "after". It works thanks :)

Comment: See my edit and see if that is what you're looking for